# Find the cycle structure of all the powers of $ (1,2,....,8)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Fro Topics in algebra  Herstein books

Find the  cycle  structure  of  all the powers of $(1,2,....,8)$?

My attempt : i take $T=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)$

$T^2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)$

i don't know how to calculate $T^2,T^3,.....,T^8 ?$

Any hints/solution will be  appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Do you understand what $T=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ means?

Comment: @jgon  ya  one cycle

Comment: So do you understand what it means as a function? And if so, can you calculate what will happen to the numbers from 1 to 8 when you apply that function twice?

Comment: u mean $T(x) =x ?$, as  i don't know  what function i have to take

Comment: I suppose I'm asking: Do you know what $T(1)$ is?

Comment: ya  $T(1) =1, T(2) =2$....as in my mind  supoose take $T= (123)(45)$  then here $T(1)=2 ,T(2)=3$

Comment: No, in this case $T(1)=2$, $T(2)=3$, $\cdots$, $T(8)=1$. Though you got it correct for your second example, so I'm a bit confused. Given this, can you work out what happens when you apply $T$ twice? What is $T^2(4)$ for example?

Comment: T(1) = 1???  T(2)=2???? So $T = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ is the  identity function and doesn't do anything.  So $T^2 = T$ because applying the identity function to the identity function is the identity function.  But... no, you are incorrect $T(1) \ne 1$.  $T(1)$ means the value that $1$ gets mapped to which is... what.

Comment: Isn't the usual notation (12345678) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ is the function that sends: $1\mapsto 2; 2\mapsto 3; $ etc.  Or if we write it as a cycle $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to .... \to 7\to 8\to ....$

If we apply it twice $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ we get $1\mapsto 2\mapsto 3$ so $1\mapsto 3$.  And $2 \mapsto 3\mapsto 4$ so $2\mapsto 4$.  And $3\mapsto 4\mapsto 5$ so $3\mapsto 5$ and so on...

It's not hard to work out we have $1\mapsto 3; 2\mapsto 4; 3\mapsto 5; 4\mapsto 6; 5\mapsto 7; 6\mapsto 8; 7\mapsto 1; 8\mapsto 2$.

As cycles this is $1\to 3\to 5\to 7\to 1$ and $2\to 4\to 6\to 8\to 2$.  And in permutation notations $(1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8)$

So $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)^2 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) = (1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8)$.

This should be easy to generalize and complete.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read $T=(1,2,...,8)$ as:

Send $1$ to $2$

Send $2$ to $ 3$

...

Send $8$ to $1.$

If you compose this twice, then $T^2$ means apply $T$ twice, ie

Send $1$ to $3.$

Send $2$ to $4.$

...

Send $8$ to $2$.